# TSQL how to change date from MMM d YYYY to YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I'm trying to do a couple of things with this query. I'll ask a separate question with the same dataset so that it makes sense in this forum.

**1)** I'm trying to change the PrevBiz date from my declare statement to be YYYYMMDD instead of Apr 6 2016. Any suggestions?

**2)** How do I get the PreviousBizDate within the select statement to show as YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD and remove the timestamp?

```
   DECLARE @TODAY       DATE    = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @PREVFIRST  CHAR(8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0), 112)
DECLARE @PREVLAST   CHAR(8) = CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), -1), 112) 
        DECLARE @PREVBIZ    CHAR(12) = DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(CHAR(12), @TODAY,112))
                            WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN -2
                            WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN -3
                            ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(CHAR(12), @TODAY, 112)))

          SELECT TOP 10
          CURRENTDATE       =@TODAY, 
          FIRST_OF_MONTH    =@PREVFIRST,
          LASTDAY_OFMONTH   =@PREVLAST,
          PREVBIZ           =@PREVBIZ,

           DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CONVERT(DATE, @TODAY,101))
            WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN -2
            WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN -3
            ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CONVERT(DATE, @TODAY, 101))) AS PREVIOUSBIZDATE,

          OpendDate 

          FROM [USBI_DW].[USBI].[vw_NameAddressBase]
          where IsCurrent = 1
```

Here's my results:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @TODAY datetime   = convert(date,GETDATE())
declare @PrevLast datetime = @today - day(@today)

declare @PrevFirst datetime = @PrevLast - day(@PrevLast)+1
declare @PREVBIZ   datetime =  DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@TODAY)
                            WHEN 'SUNDAY' THEN -2
                            WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN -3
                            ELSE -1 END,@TODAY)

          SELECT TOP 10
          CURRENTDATE       =convert(nvarchar(8),@TODAY, 112),
          FIRST_OF_MONTH    =convert(nvarchar(8),@PREVFIRST, 112),
          LASTDAY_OFMONTH   =convert(nvarchar(8),@PREVLAST, 112),
          PREVBIZ           =convert(nvarchar(8),@PREVBIZ, 112),

      OpendDate 

      FROM [USBI_DW].[USBI].[vw_NameAddressBase]
      where IsCurrent = 1
```

Be careful when use datename function... It depends on LocaleID and Language

Answer (score 1):

Check this link from Microsoft MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx it seems that the answer you are looking for is:

```
CONVERT(DATE, @TODAY, 102)
```

or

```
CONVERT(DATE, @TODAY, 112)
```